# Why is my Magento Admin Panel not loading properly all of a sudden?

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.3, css, admin-panel

Just wondering if anyone can help me, all of a sudden i cannot view the Magento Admin Panel, it seems as if the page isn't loading properly or restricted. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: check console...

Comment: Try with running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f command & php bin/magento cache:flush. If still not working then give permission 777 to var and pub folder.

Comment: I think js and css files are not found. Please check your css and js path. First see console and click on css and js file.

Answer (score 2):

Please run these command on shell

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

this is create static files and admin will be fixed.

If above solution wont work for you then you need to check `exception.log` to check the actual error

Answer (score 2):

clear / delete caches and sessions of Magento 2 below path.

```
ROOT > var > cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > page_cache > *DELETE ALL*
ROOT > var > session > *DELETE ALL*
```

Also delete old files generated in `ROOT > pub > static > DELETE ALL EXCEPT .HTACCESS`

Run Commands from your Magento root directory

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear cache and generated

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

> If magento version 2.1.x

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/generation
```

> If magento version > 2.2.x

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ generated/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

And then try to reload page